# saves a record with checkboxes list as one row in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I need to add new person with a products list witch is the checked checkboxes using codeigniter and mysql.

here is my view contains the person's form to submit including input text, checkboxes, and select element:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><p class="text-left space_p"> name </p></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" name="person[name]" class="form-control" required placeholder="person's name" />
                  </div>
                </div><!--/form-group--> 

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><p class="text-left space_p">speciality</p></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                     <select name="person[speciality]"  class="form-control" required >
                     <option value="" selected="selected" >specialities list</option>
                      <option value="ag" >Agencement</option>
                      <option value="al" >Aluminium</option>
                      <option value="pv">PVC</option>
                       <option value="oth">autre ...</option>                     
                    </select>

                  </div>
                </div><!--/form-group--> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><p class="text-left space_p">Products</p></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox"  value="p1" name="products[]">
                       menuisier
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox"  value="p2" name="products[]">
                       dancer
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox"  value="p3" name="products[]">
                       hero
                    </label>
```

here is my controller
how to get the checked checkboxes and add
how to insert the checked checkbox list for this person when submit
    public function add() {

```
$data = array(); 
$data["message"]="";
$prod=$this->input->post("products");
if ($this->input->post("btnAdd", false) )
{ 

    $Person=$this->input->post("person"); 
    if($this->PersonModel->add($Person))
        { 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 
        '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">added successfully </div>');
        redirect("/person/");
            } 
        }
        $this->layout->title('add new'); // Set page title
        $this->LoadViewBlocks("person","","",true,true,true);
        $data["bodyId"]="register-bg";
        $this->layout->view('backend/person/add', $data);
    }
```

here is my model

```
public function add($data){
        $this->db->trans_start();
         $this->db->insert($this->tableName, $data);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return  $insert_id; 
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem or your question?

Comment: add checked checkboxes in the record of the person witch I want to insert into DB

Comment: every person have a list of products (whitch are the checked checkbox) my question is how to get the list of product and add the person in DB

Comment: So please edit your question accordingly.